# Some of the tailwind classes doesn't apply

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind in my Next.js application and it sometimes behaves strangely. I could get 99% of the classes work but in some occasions classes doesn't apply at all. Just to give an example, when I add `h-48` which produces `height:12rem;` its completely fine but when its changed to number above 48 it doesn't work like `h-96`.

Another problematic class is `max-height`. Regardless of the value it doesn't apply at all. Same thing happens with any classes that has point in it. For example `m-h-0.5`.

At the same time, if I change the config file and assign `h-96` to any value it still applies. What do you think that might be causing tailwind to behave in that way?

Comment: Could be a typo, but just to point out that [`max-height`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/max-height) is applied as `max-h-0.5` in TailwindCSS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am sure that its not typo but something else.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue just now and found the fix.

This happens if you don't have a `postcss.config.js` config in your root. This happened to me because I was upgrading from an older version of Tailwind and for some reason that config hadn't been generated initially. You can use tailwind to generate a new one - just run the below code in your root.

```
npx tailwindcss init -p
```