# Why does Tailwind apply some selectors but not others?

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm running into an issue with applying `flex-basis`, `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `background-color` through Tailwind.

I'm mostly concerned with the `flex` properties, but I imagine the strange `background-color` behavior may be related.

Tailwind applies the `flex` and `flex-wrap` selectors on the parent just fine, but ignores the selectors on the children.

To make troubleshooting specific to Tailwind and not my project setup, I recreated this issue in [codepen](https://codepen.io/johnhodge/pen/poQvELz) and it's still happening. So, I'm doubtful the cause is my project setup (which are [possible causes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65680735/some-of-the-tailwind-classes-doesnt-apply) I've seen elsewhere).

Lastly, I noticed that I can apply these styles myself with plain CSS and everything works as expected. So, I think the problem is related to how I'm using Tailwind in the HTML. But I'm not sure how I'm creating this issue.

Can someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my HTML:

```html
<main class="bg-slate-700">
  <section class="flex flex-wrap">
    <div class="shrink basis-1/5 grow child">
      <img class="p-4" src="https://picsum.photos/2000">
    </div>
    <div class="shrink basis-1/5 grow child">
      <img class="p-4" src="https://picsum.photos/2000">
    </div>
    <div class="shrink basis-1/5 grow child">
      <img class="p-4" src="https://picsum.photos/2000">
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Here's my CSS:

```css
/*
I would think the CSS below would render the same results as the Tailwind utility classes. They're even in the same order.

If you comment out the CSS below, you'll see these styles are no longer applied.
*/

.child {
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have added to Tailwind Play and it looks as though it is working as expected: https://play.tailwindcss.com/D7tLicA40W. Check Generated CSS > Utilities for the generated CSS. So it would appear your setup isn't producing the same output. Can you check what is being output?

Answer (score 0):

seems you might be using incorrect class names with Tailwind. Try these adjustments:

Replace `shrink` with `flex-shrink`.
Use `flex-1` or `w-1/5` instead of `basis-1/5`.
Substitute `grow` with `flex-grow`.

Your updated divs should look something like this:

```
<div class="flex-shrink flex-1 w-1/5">
  <img class="p-4" src="https://picsum.photos/2000">
</div>
```